# jquery ajax posting failed not returning an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

ive read some questions related to my question but i can't find a solution

in some part of my website. posting a single value to a php page works

so i searched passing multiple values using ajax and applied it to my website
but i says posting failed

this is the php code. i tried running it to my server by passing directly a data to the php and it works like this $temp1 = "0001"
this is the inserdocument.php file

```
$temp1 = $_POST['dtnum'];
$temp2 = $_POST['ddoctitle'];
$temp3 = $_POST['ddoctype'];
$temp4 = $_POST['ddoccontent'];
$temp5 = $_POST['ddocdatefilled'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_insertdocument (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $temp1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30); 
$stmt->bindParam(2, $temp2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50); 
$stmt->bindParam(3, $temp3, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50); 
$stmt->bindParam(4, $temp4, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10); 
$stmt->bindParam(5, $temp5, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10); 
$stmt->execute();
```

and this is my ajax code. i even tried adding try and catch but the catch returns nothing.

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inserdocument.php",
                data: ({dtnum: tnum, ddoctitle: doctitle, ddoctype: doctype, ddoccontent: doccontent, ddocdatefilled: docdatefilled})
            })
            .done(function (msg) {
                alert("Data Saved: " + msg);

        //$('#response').html(msg);
            })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Posting failed." );
    });
```

Comment: return true from the php file

Comment: What is the response of your AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

im sorry for posting i found out that the problem is here
url: "inserdocument.php"
it should be
url: "insertdocument.php"

typographical error. im concentrating at the passing of data, i didn't notice the php filename is incorrect. sorry

Comment: Always check network tab in your console when working with Ajax.

Comment: Tick your answer as the correct answer to close the question :)